# Meteor drop collection after every query

Tags: meteor

I am writing an application which communicates with an API and stores the response in a Meteor Collection so I can have the power of mongo to sort/filter.

I would like to clear the collection for every new result set.  But a Meteor Collection is persistent.

What is the preferred way of clearing the collection?  I know you can drop the meteor collection, but is that the preferred method?

Help appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about creating a local mongo collection which will be available on client side only. To create a client-side collection, just don't give it a name argument.

```
//This collection is client-only, and will not be sync with server
   myCollection = new Mongo.Collection();


//To be more explicit, you can use `null` for the name:
  myCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

Once you are done using the data empty the collection

```
myCollection.remove({});
```

Comment: No need to even `remove`; just create a new collection every time and old ones will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

`myCollection.remove({})` is the syntax for removing all documents from a collection. This will only work on the server unless the collection is a client-side collection as per @Nakib's example. Otherwise documents can only be deleted by `_id` on the client side. Normally your allow/deny rules should block any attempt to delete anything on the client as it provides a great attack vector.

Answer (score -2):

Not completely familiar with the Meteor best practice but if you were going to clear out an array in javascript the best practice would be to run the following.

`myArrary.length = 0;`

For more information I recommend this [blog post by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/empty-array) where he details the reasoning behind zeroing out an array as follows:

> Setting the length equal to zero empties the existing array, not
>   creating another array! This helps you to avoid pointer issues with
>   arrays as well.

Comment: It's more of Mongo, not Meteor. And for Mongo, setting collection's length to 0 won't work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and now I see that my answer is way off base.